# for loop and string slicing gives unexpected output

Tags: c#

i am starting to learn C#, my first language i learned is Python and i switched to Visual Studio Code for it from Pycharm.
I am trying to code a simple TicTacToe as exercise, when i loop trough my TicTacToe grid to see if one of the empty fields marked with numbers is still avaliable, i get an unexpected output.

The expected output would be 1-9, but its not, i am not allowed to post images so not sure how to say/show it.

When i use char as data type the correct value seems to be there in '' as second value, but how do access it?

in both cases comparision operator do not yield the expected results!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public static class Programm
    {
        static int meow = 1;
        static string board_roof = "-------";
        static string board_mid1 = "|1|2|3|";
        static string board_mid2 = "|4|5|6|";
        static string board_mid3 = "|7|8|9|";
        static string board_all_default = board_roof + Environment.NewLine + board_mid1 + Environment.NewLine +board_mid2 + Environment.NewLine +board_mid3 + Environment.NewLine + board_roof;
          
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Acces_board2(meow);
        }
        
        public static void Acces_board2(int lfm) {      
            for(int gas=0; gas<board_all_default.Length; gas++) {
                bool result = char.IsNumber(board_all_default[gas]);
                if (result) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{board_all_default[gas]} , {lfm}");
                    if(lfm < board_all_default[gas]) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"True");
                    }
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

doesnt matter if i use

```
if (lfm < board_all_default[gas])
```

or

```
int checkme = board_all_default[gas];
if (lfm < checkme)
```

it never works, that would be no issue in python, i have no clue whats happening

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, what this program is supposed to do. There appears to be a large amount of irrelevant code, such as commented-out code and various `WriteLine`s. I suggest you read through [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before you continue, and make good use of the debugger. Once you can explain how this is supposed to work, and what exactly is going wrong, we may be able to help

Comment: I am making a small TicTacToe board from different strings saved in different variabels, i concatinate them togheter to a board, than i loop trough the board and try to only get the matches that a numbers 1-9 and compare to the user input if it still exists in the board, the reason its < only for test purposes, i doesnt work with == and the output of < or > is not correct!

Comment: `lfm` is an `int` with the value of `1`, which is always going to be less than `board_all_default[gas]` (after implicitly getting the Unicode value of that character) because the Unicode for `1` is 49 or 0x31. But it's not clear what that loop is supposed to do, you only ever call it once with the value `1`

Comment: the idea of the loop is to search the tictactoe board for a number, if its still in the board i would place an X or O, its just an exercise, to learn C#, so i guess i have to convert lfm to a Char and than use == to get what i want ?
instead of converting board_all_default[gas] to int